# Laravel Curl Error

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm trying to send a curl request with Curl from a Laravel 5 controller.

```
public function funcname(){
$ch = curl_init();
$message = http_build_query([])
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The response is:

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()
```

Could someone point me on the mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `curl` php module? Check the output of `php -m`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems curl is not enabled. Instruction for most Windows configurations:

Locate your `php.ini`, open it and find `extension=php_curl.dll` and uncomment this line (remove `;`). Then restart Apache.

On Linux line is `extension=curl.so`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Controller` is under a namespace so you should use `\curl_init()` instead of `curl_init()` (Also `curl` should be enabled, notice other comments). Also, you don't need to use `curl` since you are using `Laravel` then utilize the [Guzzle Http Client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/). Check [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/guzzle-php-http-client/) for more. This is a very simplified example to make a post request using `Guzzle`:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post("http://example.com", [
    'headers' => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'],
    'body'    => ['field_name' => 'value']
]);

var_dump($response->getStatusCode());
```

Guzzle will use `curl` (by default) or whatever it needs to use.